# Angular - Factory components inside for

Tags: javascript, angular

Im using Angular Gridster 2 to build a Dashboards of components. These components, we call gadgets, may have different selector  (so component) but I know it at runtime after a backend/database call.

Other than this, the code of the grid is inside an Angular Library but the components to be rendered are stored in the main application.

So I was thinking this approach:

The Library Component receives several input parameters. An object about the Dashboard (with title etc...), a list of Item to display (objects that implements GridsterItem Interface), and a factory_component the caller implements to build component dynamically.

LIBRARY DASHBOARD COMPONENT:

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() dashboard  : D3AbstractDashboard = new D3AbstractDashboard();
  @Input() gadgets    : GridsterItem[]      = [];
  @Input() factory_component : Function      = undefined;

...
}

<gridster [options]="options">
  <gridster-item *ngFor="let item of gadgets" [item]="item">
       {{ factory_component(item) }}
  </gridster-item>
</gridster>
```

CALLER COMPONENT

The caller use the Library component in its HTML passing the three parameters.
It makes the calls to database to get the dashboard's data and the list of widget that it converts in the Class that implements GristerItem. This class has a property that is the "selector" of component relative to that widget.

```
<dashboard
   [dashboard]          = "dashboard"
   [gadgets]            = "grid_items"
   [factory_component]  = "factoryComponent"
>

</dashboard>

class MyApGristerItem implements GristerItem
...
constructor(gadget: Gadget)
{
        this.x          = gadget.x;
        this.y          = gadget.y;
        this.cols       = gadget.cols;
        this.rows       = gadget.rows;
        this.selector   = gadget.selector; //for example my-foo-component
        this.data       = gadget .data;
}
```

As you can see, the Library component return the Item to the caller using factory function and this route works great.

```
//Caller Component
factoryComponent(item)
{
    console.log(item);
}
```

In console I have all the items the caller has passed inside the grid_items (I know its a bit tricly becase the caller recieves the gadget it has passed)

Now what I need is to render the relative component with the selector inside the item object.

Ipotetically the result has to be:

```
<item.selector [data] = "item.data"> </item.selector>
```

For example

```
<my-foo-component  [data] = "item.data"> </my-foo-component>
```

MyFooComponet will be a component with an

```
@Input() data : Objects = {};
```

that receives the DB data property for that gadget that explains what to do.

Comment: Angular doesn't want you to create a component by hand, you should use `@ContentChild`. Look at angular material. They use this approach and it is the cleanest we have.

Comment: I don't get how to use the contentchild decorator. The component must be build at runtime. Until that time, I don't have any component to look for with ContentChild.

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way to create an element by a selector.

```
<dashboard 
 [dashboard]="dashboard"
 [gadgets]="grid_items"
 [ngSwitch]="componentTag"
>
  <gadget1 *ngSwitchCase="'gadget1'"></gadget1>
  <gadget2 *ngSwitchCase="'gadget2'"></gadget2>
  <gadget3 *ngSwitchCase="'gadget3'"></gadget3>
</dashboard>
```

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() dashboard: D3AbstractDashboard = new D3AbstractDashboard();
  @Input() gadgets: GridsterItem[] = [];
  @ContentChild() component?: Gadget;

  ...
}
```

If you need to create much more elements types, or don't want them to be part of the bundle you might want to use Angular Material Portal (https://material.angular.io/cdk/portal/overview)

Comment: I cant bind every gadget in the CallerComponent. I'm now trying to use Portals but I cant figure out how to use. It always used to reload the same component but I have to create multiple portalHost each ones with different components...

Comment: On every change of component you need to create new portal and destroy the old one

Comment: In my case I need to build a Portal for each component in *ngFor and than fill it with Component but I cant figure out how. In the example on the site, they re-use the same Portal to change content. I Don't need to change because I need ALL the component in the pages at the same time.

Comment: If you need multiple you can either use `ngFor` with `ngSwitch` or multiple portals, up to you...